# woocommerce default order widget showing by checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've modified the code to create a widget to showing woocommerce default sort based on checkbox But in my code the checkboxes is show on woocommerse shop page  but when I click on it there is not working.
Also I want to show the product based on Ajax but I don't know how can I do it.
Any help is appreciated.

```
class Hadhad_WC_Ordering_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'hadhad_wc_ordering_widget',
            __('WooCommerce Ordering Widget', 'text_domain'),
            array(
                'description' => esc_html__('Display product sorting checkboxes for WooCommerce', 'text_domain'),
                'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from the database.
     */
    public function form($instance)
    {
        // Set widget defaults
        $defaults = array(
            'title' => '',
            'orderby' => array(), // Initialize as an empty array
        );

        // Parse current settings with defaults
        extract(wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults));
        ?>

        <?php // Widget Title   ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php _e('Widget Title', 'text_domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
        </p>

        <?php // Checkbox options ?>
        <p>
            <label><?php _e('Select sorting options:', 'text_domain'); ?></label><br>
            <?php
            $catalog_orderby_options = apply_filters(
                'WooCommerce_catalog_orderby',
                array(
                    'menu_order' => __('Default sorting', 'WooCommerce'),
                    'popularity' => __('Sort by popularity', 'WooCommerce'),
                    'rating' => __('Sort by average rating', 'WooCommerce'),
                    'date' => __('Sort by latest', 'WooCommerce'),
                    'price' => __('Sort by price: low to high', 'WooCommerce'),
                    'price-desc' => __('Sort by price: high to low', 'WooCommerce'),
                )
            );

            foreach ($catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name) :
                $checked = in_array($id, $orderby) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('orderby_' . $id)); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('orderby[]')); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('orderby_' . $id)); ?>"><?php echo __($name, 'woocommerce'); ?></label><br>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from the database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? sanitize_text_field($new_instance['title']) : '';
        // If checkboxes are used, save the selected values as an array
        $instance['orderby'] = isset($new_instance['orderby']) ? array_map('sanitize_text_field', $new_instance['orderby']) : array();

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of the widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from the database.
     */
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if (!empty($instance['title'])) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']) . $args['after_title'];
        }

        $catalog_orderby_options = apply_filters(
            'WooCommerce_catalog_orderby',
            array(
                'menu_order' => __('Default sorting', 'WooCommerce'),
                'popularity' => __('Sort by popularity', 'WooCommerce'),
                'rating' => __('Sort by average rating', 'WooCommerce'),
                'date' => __('Sort by latest', 'WooCommerce'),
                'price' => __('Sort by price: low to high', 'WooCommerce'),
                'price-desc' => __('Sort by price: high to low', 'WooCommerce'),
            )
        );

        $default_orderby = wc_get_loop_prop('is_search') ? 'relevance' : apply_filters('WooCommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('WooCommerce_default_catalog_orderby', ''));
        $orderby = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_GET['orderby'])) : $default_orderby;

        $html = '<form class="WooCommerce-ordering" method="get">
            <ul class="ordering-options">'; // Use an unordered list for checkboxes

        foreach ($catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name) :
            $html .= '<li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="orderby[]" value="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ' . (in_array($id, (array)$orderby) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . '>
                <label for="' . esc_attr($id) . '">' . __($name, 'woocommerce') . '</label>
            </li>';
        endforeach;

        $html .= '</ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1" />
            ' . wc_query_string_form_fields(null, array('orderby', 'submit', 'paged', 'product-page')) . '</form>';

        echo $html;

        // WordPress core after_widget hook (always include )
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
}

// Register the widget
function register_WooCommerce_ordering_widget()
{
    register_widget('Hadhad_WC_Ordering_Widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_WooCommerce_ordering_widget');
```